# continuous animation within UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation

I'm trying to add a continuous animation onto my UITableViewCell-Subclass.
It's a rather easy one with an Image fading in and out (fading between 0.4 alpha and 1.0),
what I've tried so far ist the following:

```
-(void)animateRecordingIndicator{

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"RecordingIndicatorAnimation" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];

    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self]; 
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationFinished)];

    if (animatedImageView.alpha == 0.4) 
        animatedImageView.alpha = 1.0;
    else 
        animatedImageView.alpha = 0.4;    

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

the code within animationFinished is as follows:

```
-(void)animationFinished{
    if (doShowAnimation) {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(animateRecordingIndicator) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    }
}
```

what I expect should be clear by now, but what I get is simply a crash with Xcode loading Stackframes more or less eternally :)

Comment: Quick question before I answer, is iOS3 compatibility mandatory?

Comment: na not really, i'd just leave out the animation on devices running anything lower than 4.1 or 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [UIView class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html), you are now discouraged from using the commitAnimations method.  Instead use the following:

```
animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:
```

I imagine the infinite recursion you are encountering is related to Apple's reasons for making that recommendation.

Comment: thanks for your hint, its animating now. unfortunately the application blocks after the animation starts and user input is no longer possible. also only the first of n tableViewCells get the animation to work.